# Why purchased music is not synched on U1 on Windows7?

Tags: ubuntu-one, music, mp3

I can't determine why my already purchased music isn't available on Windows 7. Could someone give me a hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was your music purchased through Ubuntu One Music Store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not synchronized by default. You need to subscribe the folder in the control panel on the folders tab, for the folder to be synchronized. You will also then have to add that folder to your music player by hand on Windows.

They will be located in your home directory (profile folder), under the `.ubuntuone/Purchased from Ubuntu One/` sub-directory.

Comment: I have already done that. Checkmark set.

Comment: @Petra please do not edit answers to add a reply comment to them. Use the add comment feature.

Comment: I solved it by using the UbuntuOne music webinterface and by clicking the "Try again" buttons behind the files. This seemed to "re-download" the music files from Ubuntu.